# why file_exists return true all the time

Tags: php

Why the operation if the file is exists is still returns 1
  Although there is no file name

```
$file_exists_file_var = file_exists("../../images_ad/***If it is empty***");
```

Example :

```
$file_exists_file_var = file_exists("../../images_ad/");
if ($file_exists_file_var == 1) {
echo 'File exists';
} else {
   echo 'File does not exist';
}
```

Comment: a directory is a file as well

Comment: Why do you use a `file` function on a directory?

Comment: The test was supposed to be this way $file_exists_file_var = file_exists("../../images_ad/myfile.jpg");

Comment: Is there another way?

Answer (score 7):

> file_exists — Checks whether a file or directory exists

If you leave out the filename and only point to a directory and that directory exists – it will return true.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php